# Why does my child React component need to be wrapped inside a function to detect parent state change?

Tags: reactjs

This is my working code, and below it is what I'd like my code to look like but doesn't work:

I'd like my MainComponent's selectDay method to change TableComponent's urls for fetching data based on which day is selected

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        urls: [{
            appointmentsUrl: "/api/appointments",
            callsUrl: "/api/calls"
        }]
    }
}

selectDay(day) {
    if(day.key == 1) {
        this.setState({
            urls: [{
                appointmentsUrl: "/api/appointments",
                callsUrl: "/api/calls"
            }]
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({
            urls: [{
                appointmentsUrl: "/api/appointments2",
                callsUrl: "/api/calls2"
            }]
        })
    }
}

    render() {
    var calendarData = [//init some array of dates];


    return (
        <div>
            <TopMenuComponent/>
            <div className="contentContainer">
                {
                    ((urls)=>{
                        return(
                            <TableComponent key={urls[0].appointmentsUrl} appointmentsUrl={urls[0].appointmentsUrl} callsUrl={urls[0].callsUrl}/>
                        )
                    })(this.state.urls)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This works, but what I would like is something like is something like:

```
<TableComponent appointmentsUrl={this.state.appointmentsUrl} callsUrl={this.state.callsUrl}/>
```

And initialize the state as: `this.state= {appointmentsUrl: "/api/appointments",
            callsUrl: "/api/calls"}`

Comment: why you want to write that ? state is an object how you will access in that way ??

Comment: You're right, let me rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your state in the structure you represented in the question, and you want to use the first object in that array (assuming you have the destructuring syntax enabled):

```
function render() {
  const [firstUrlObj] = this.state.urls
  return (
    <div>
      <TopMenuComponent/>
      <div className="contentContainer">
        <TableComponent appointmentsUrl={firstUrlObj.appointmentsUrl} callsUrl={firstUrlObj.callsUrl}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you want to render the whole array:

```
function render() {
  const urls = this.state.urls
  return (
    <div>
      <TopMenuComponent/>
      <div className="contentContainer">
        { urls.map(urlObj => <TableComponent appointmentsUrl={urlObj.appointmentsUrl} callsUrl={urlObj.callsUrl}/>) }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you have a single object in the array and you don't plan to have more, I suggest looking at the other answer.